# Why can't I spin a Pokéstop?

Tags: pokemon-go, technical-issues

I was playing Pokémon GO recently (on iOS). The game was running fine, and there were no problems whatsoever until I spun a Pokéstop. It didn't come up with anything at all, apart from the error message "Try Again Later".

I did try again later, and I wasn't moving at the time, but I still couldn't get it to spin correctly. This was on every Pokéstop I tried and it lasted more than 24 hours. I can spin it now, but every now and then, it seems to give me a 24 hour ban!

I know that it is not a softban, since I am able to battle gyms, catch Pokémon, place them in gyms and collect my Pokécoins. Also, my Pokémon seem to be coming out of the gyms unnaturally often.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what (if any) possible solutions to this might be?

Answer (score 6):

This is in most cases becaus of a problem with your connection with the servers.
Try to check if your connection is okay.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, this tends to be because of a connection issue.  One way to diagnose this problem is to look for the "spinning ball of death".  In the upper right hand corner of the game you'll see a spinning white pokeball every time the game servers are being accessed.  If you see it spinning frequently or non-stop some/all server interactions will fail.  This can result in "failed to spin" pokestops, as well as other behaviors like "failed to start attack" on pokemon you can see but can't engage.  Some things to try:

- Try to fix your connection

  - Force quit the app and restart
  - Turn on airplane mode until your connection drops, then turn it back off
  - Disable WiFi
- Attempt to spin a different Pokestop, then try again

Bear in mind that a failed Pokestop spin can sometimes still trigger the Pokestop cooldown (even when your connection is good).  In these cases, it will take 5 minutes before you can spin the Pokestop again.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before and it's probably because of a bad connection with the servers that Niantic needs to fix.

Answer (score -1):

it's because there is a daily and weekly limit for pokestops. I hit it alot with my auto catcher. I'm not sure what the actual limit is tho, other than the weekly one is rolling, so you can hit that limit everyday

Comment: Do you have a source for this said limit? During major events (Go Fest, Kanto Day, etc), I’ll hit up Pokéstops hundreds of times in a single day